# AngularJS 1 - ng-repeat not re-rendering after array push

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to make a simpliest chat app in Angular 1.

Controller code:

```
app.controller('mainCtrl', function ($scope, $rootScope, $routeParams, $location, $http) {
    $scope.messages=[{'name':'user','text':'test'}];
    $scope.submitMessage = function () {
    $scope.messages.push({'name':'newuser','text':$scope.mymessage});
}
});
```

Template:

```
<div class="page-content" ng-controller="mainCtrl" ng-init="init()">
<div class="messages">
<p class="chat-message" ng-repeat="message in messages"><span class="username">{{message.name}}: </span>{{message.text}}</p>
</div>
<div style="clear:both"></div>
<form ng-submit="submitMessage()" ng-controller="mainCtrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="mymessage" class="message-input" ></input>
</form>
```

When trying to console.log the $scope.messages array, it shows the new values, but the list itself does not change at all. What can be the reason?

Answer (score 2):

You've got `ng-controller="mainCtrl"` defined twice, this will actually instantiate 2 different instances of the controller, so the messages you push will be on the array in the *second instance of your controller* while you're repeating over the messages that are on the *first instance of your controller*.

You only need it on the surrounding div, everything that is nested inside this tag will be able to access the `$scope` on your controller.

```
<div class="page-content" ng-controller="mainCtrl" ng-init="init()">
  <div class="messages">
    <p class="chat-message" ng-repeat="message in messages"><span class="username">{{message.name}}: </span>{{message.text}}</p>
  </div>
  <div style="clear:both"></div>
  <form ng-submit="submitMessage()">
    <input type="text" ng-model="mymessage" class="message-input"/>
  </form>
</div>
```